# Как переписать функцию быстрого блочного чтения файла на Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Дана функция для posix:

```
static uintmax_t wc(char const *fname)
{
    static const auto BUFFER_SIZE = 16*1024;
    int fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
        handle_error("open");

    /* Advise the kernel of our access pattern.  */
    posix_fadvise(fd, 0, 0, 1);  // FDADVICE_SEQUENTIAL

    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    uintmax_t lines = 0;

    while(size_t bytes_read = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE))
    {
        if(bytes_read == (size_t)-1)
            handle_error("read failed");
        if (!bytes_read)
            break;

        for(char *p = buf; (p = (char*) memchr(p, '\n', (buf + bytes_read) - p)); ++p)
            ++lines;
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Мне непонятно два момента, как передать путь в `wchar_t` (код у нас современный)) в функцию `open`. Второй момент, что именно делает `posix_fadvise` и как адаптировать ее под Windows?

Comment: По поводу того что делает — [man posix_fadvice](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=posix_fadvise&category=2&russian=0)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а есть ли виндовой аналог? Случайное не это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780543(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: нет, это похоже аналог `posix_madvice ()` (нет в Linux)... предложить не могу — в winapi не силён...

Comment: Вызывайте `CreateFileW` с флагом `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`.

Comment: @VTT, оформите как ответ.